# How do I make a form (iframe) inside transparent box not transparent?

Tags: iframe, transparency, transparent, css

I have an iframe that points to a form.  That Iframe is inside a css class that I have made transparent.  The fields of the form and the button are also transparent but i do not want them to be.  I do, however, want the background of the form to remain transparent.  My site is up at avidest.com/zamchick.  What should I do?  Here is my css:

```
.formbox{
  float: right; 
  width: 48%;
  padding-top: 90px; 
  padding-right: 40px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 }
```

And here is the html with the iframe:

```
  <div class="formbox">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     document.write(unescape("%3Ciframe id=\"fb_iframe\" src=\"testform4.php" 
     + window.location.search + "\" width=\"548\" height=\"787\"allowtransparency=\"true\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\"%3E&lt;a href=\"formio.php\" title=\"formio\"&gt;formio&lt;/a&gt;%3C/iframe%3E"));</script>
    <noscript>
     <iframe width="548" height="787" 
       style="border:none; background:transparent;overflow:hidden;"
     id="fb_iframe" src="testform4/testform4.html">
    &lt;a href="testform4.php" title="testform4"&gt;formio&lt;/a&gt;
    </iframe>
    </noscript>
  </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the entire element transparent, you can apply a transparent background to it using RGBA values:

Remove `opacity:0.6;` from the `.formbox` class and add

`background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);`

The first 3 parameters represent the Red, Green and Blue values, while the last one accepts the Alpha value and ranges from 0 to 1.
This will work with [all modern CSS3 capable](http://caniuse.com/css3-colors) browsers. You may want to provide fallback for older browsers though:

```
   background: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* The Fallback */
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
```

If you want to support *really old* browsers, I suggest checking out [this article](http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/) by the amazing Lea Verou which suggests using a semi-transparent png image, and a PHP script to automate it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but then when I click on one of the buttons and the form expands, it takes on the gray background below.  Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: This sounds like an unrelated issue. The URL you posted is no longer available. Can you please provide a new URL for me to look at?